# Why is the dipole moment of chloromethane larger than the dipole moment of fluoromethane?

Tags: halides, dipole

[On the Pauling electronegativity scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity), fluorine and chlorine are 3.98 and 3.16, respectively.

Since the dipole moment is dependent on electronegativity, why is the dipole moment of chloromethane *larger* than the dipole moment of fluoromethane?

I guess that the smaller size of the s orbital in the fluorine atom has something to do with this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dipole moment is not just about charges, it also has $L$ term. Bond length of $\ce{C-Cl}$ is greater than $\ce{C-F}$ and in this case, that is more dominating factor.

The dipole moment is in order

$$\ce{CH3Cl} \gt \ce{CH3F} \gt \ce{CH3Br} \gt \ce{CH3I}$$

You can see that electronegativity plays a more dominating role in $\ce{CH3X}$ when $\ce{X}$ is $\ce{Br}$/$\ce{I}$.